# Getting only one picture on screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Whit this code i'm trying to shuffle som pictures, but i get only one picture on screen.

Can someone tell me what i'm missing? The ilist has 9 different values, but it is only the first values that gets on screen.
All the pictures are in the folder.

Thanks in advance.

```
protected void btnShuffle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    List<int> MyRandomList = Shuffeld();

    List<int> ilist = new List<int>();

    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[0] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[1] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[2] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[3] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[4] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[5] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[6] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[7] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[8] + ".jpg");


}
public static List<int> Shuffeld() {

    List<int> ilist = new List<int>();

    while (ilist.Count < 9)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int a = r.Next(1, 10);
        while (!ilist.Contains(a))
        {
            ilist.Add(a);
        }
        }


    return ilist;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need one image control for each image you wish to display**

The problem is you only have one image on the page, `img1`. Obviously you can't display nine images with only one image on the page.  You need nine.

The most obvious (not necessarily most elegant) fix is to change...

```
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[0] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[1] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[2] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[3] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[4] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[5] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[6] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[7] + ".jpg");
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[8] + ".jpg");
```

...to...

```
    img1.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[0] + ".jpg");
    img2.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[1] + ".jpg");
    img3.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[2] + ".jpg");
    img4.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[3] + ".jpg");
    img5.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[4] + ".jpg");
    img6.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[5] + ".jpg");
    img7.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[6] + ".jpg");
    img8.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[7] + ".jpg");
    img9.Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[8] + ".jpg");
```

And of course make sure `img1`, `img2`, `img3`, `img4`, `img5`, `img6`, `img7`, `img8`, and `img9` are all defined on the page.

Now if you want an *elegant* solution, maybe you can find a way to use an array of image controls instead of nine separate controls, or perhaps embed your image controls [in a repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx). Then you could use a `for` loop instead of writing one line of code for each image. But that would be a topic for a different question.

**P.S.**

If you need to generate a list of numbers from 1 to 9 in random order, a real quick shortcut is this:

```
Random r = new Random();
var randomList = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).OrderBy( a => r.Next());
```

Answer (score 1):

---

I think you always set your `Attributes["src"]` to the same image object: `img1`.

If it's not the case you should use a for... Anyway, you should use a for.

Edit: An example of for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        imgList[i].Attributes["src"] = ResolveUrl("~/Stendalen3/gfx/Puslespil/" + MyRandomList[i] + ".jpg")
    }
```

(I supposed you have a list of object image.)

Comment: Might be worth the OP's time for you to give an example of the for loop :)